# ng2-charts changing chart color dinamically makes chart behave weird

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework, ng2-charts

I've been looking for a way to change the color of my bar Chart indicator for a couple of days now. Its an Ionic-angular 3.9.2 app. I've tried many of the workarounds posted in here to no avail. I found my own way of doing it but barchart behaves really weird. First, I had to put a button to rerun a function with an API call that brings data to my graph, because it wont show if the function runs only one time. On the other hand, columns get really thin.

Graph if I dont use the show flag(loads normally)
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/16280628/45188356-56c57b80-b20a-11e8-879b-a6d1ed7430d1.png

Graph if I do(takes a button click to load)
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/16280628/45188227-e0287e00-b209-11e8-8e05-ab6568eeb6d3.png

Thanks, any help would be much appreciated

Info:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.11",
    "@ionic-native/core": "~4.11.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "~4.11.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "~4.11.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.2",
    "cordova-android": "~7.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.0.5",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^2.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "1.3.3",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.6.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.11",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
```

Code:

HTML:

```
   <div style="display: block" *ngIf="show">
    <canvas baseChart height="" 
            [datasets]="barChartData"
            [labels]="barChartLabels"
            [options]="barChartOptions"
            [colors]="barChartColors"
            [legend]="barChartLegend"
            [chartType]="barChartType"
            (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
            (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></canvas>
  </div>
```

JS:

```
public barChartOptions:any = {
scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
responsive: true,
legend: {display:false},
scales: {
yAxes: [{id: 'y-axis-1', type: 'linear', position: 'left', ticks: {min: 0, max:60}}]
}
};

public barChartLabels:string[] = ['L', 'M', 'M', 'J', 'V', 'S', 'D'];
public barChartType:string = 'bar';
public barChartLegend:boolean = true;

public barChartData:any[] = [
{data: [0]}
]; 

public barChartColors:Array<any> = [{}];
leerDatos() {       //FUNCTION THAT MAKES THE API CALL

//clear out the previous array contents
this.info_items = [];
this.datos_actividad = [];
this.datos_color = [];
this.errorConexion = false;

//Create the loading indicator
let loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
content: "Obteniendo perfil de usuario..."
});

//Show the loading indicator    
loader.present();

this.serviceWiseapp.obtenerActividadFisica().then(
data => {

loader.dismiss();


if (data) {

//cWe have data, so lets do something with it
this.info_items = this.formatInfoItems(data.actividadFisica);

for(let i=0; i < this.info_items.length; i++){
this.datos_actividad[i] = this.info_items[i].duracionActividadFisica;
}
this.barChartData = this.datos_actividad;

this.barChartColors[0].backgroundColor = 

this.obtenerColores(this.info_items);  // Only way ive 
                                                                                                    //found to change color dinamically
    this.errorConexion = false;



// console.log(this.barChartData);

this.show=true;
//this.barChartColors = this.datos_color;
} else {
//This really should never happen
this.errorConexion = true;
}

},
error => {

//Hide the loading indicator
loader.dismiss();
this.errorConexion = true;
}
);
}
```

...

```
private obtenerColores(info_items:any){
let tmpArray:any = [];

if (info_items) {

for (let i = 0; i < info_items.length; i++) { 
if(info_items[i].duracionActividadFisica >= 35){
tmpArray.push(          
'rgba(0, 192, 0, 0.6'
);  
}else if(info_items[i].duracionActividadFisica >= 20){
tmpArray.push(          
'rgba(255,255,0,0.6)'
);  
}else {
tmpArray.push(          
'rgba(255, 25, 25, 0.6)'
);  
}    
}
};

return tmpArray;
}
```

[image: Chart]